# Copy folder into multiple folders

Tags: macos, folders

I have a folder that I need to copy into 400 other folders. Instead of writing code to do this is there an easy way to paste into multiple folders?

Comment: Are the names of the destination folders in some kind of sequence?

Comment: The names of the destination folders are names of counties and cities. I already wrote the code to do it so it isn't that big of a deal anymore but it would be nice next time.